# Gary and Eric's life spans are both uniform distributions, find Probability Gary dies first.

Tags: probability

There are two newborns, Gary and Eric. The future lifetime of Gary is uniformly distributed between $0$ to $60$ years. The future lifetime of Eric is uniformly distributed between $0$ to $40$ years. Their future lifetimes are independent.

Calculate the probability that Gary dies first.

---

I tried to just do $${1\over 60}\over{1\over 40}$$ and I get $$2\over3$$ but I just can't see how Gary's death being first would have a higher probability.

Comment: You should write down the joint density of Gary's lifetime $X$ and Eric's lifetime $Y$ and integrate it over the set $\{ x<y \}$.

Comment: would the joint density just be $1\over 60*40$?

Comment: It is that value on a particular set, but you need to write down what that set is in order to get your limits of integration right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(G)$ be the probability that Gary dies first. The probability can be derived by $$P(G) = P(G| \text{Gary lives}\geq 40)P(\text{Gary lives}<40)+ P(G| \text{Gary lives}<40)P(\text{Gary lives}<40)$$
The first term is always $0$, while the second is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$.

Or, we can split the $40$ years of Eric into very small pieces of time $dt$. If Eric dies at time $t$ and Gary dies before Eric, the probability is $\frac{t}{60}\cdot \frac{dt}{40}$, hence the probability that Gary dies first is $$\int_0^{40} \frac{t}{2400} \ dt = \frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$U_G \sim Uni(0,60)$$

$$U_E \sim Uni(0,40)$$

where $U_G$ and $U_E$ are independent.

\begin{align}
P(U_G < U_E) &= P(U_G < U_E|U_G >40)P(U_G>40)+P(U_G<U_E|U_G  \leq 40) P(U_G \leq 40) \\
&= 0+\frac12 \left( \frac23\right) \\
&= \frac13
\end{align}